# Intel Pin instrumentation to execute once

Tags: intel-pin

I am looking for a possibility of if I could insert an instrumentation before an instruction, then once that executed, want to remove that instrumentation so that I don't have multiple calls for the same instruction.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if I get your point. Do you have some instruction which you want to instrument only once? For example, an instruction in some kind of loop? If that is the case, you can use different APIs in the instrumentation function to zero down that particular instruction and instead of doing an Insert_call, simply perform the analysis in the instrumentation function. The instrumentation function simply works on the static code and hence will get executed only once.

Comment: An instruction may be instrumented more than once.

Comment: When I have done an insert_call to instrument a call back method for an instruction, then every time that instruction executed, my call back method will be called. But, for my purpose, it is fine enough for me if I only have single time call back. So, if I could remove the instrumented call back just after that instruction being executed first time, I can achieve this easily. As intel pin is a dynamic binary instrumentation process, so I assume that could be possible?